# Accessing values - Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

You are given a dictionary crypt of type [String:String] which has values for all lowercase letters. The crypt dictionary represents a way to encode a message. For example, if crypt["h"] = "@" and crypt["i"] = "!" the encoded version of the message "hi" will be "@!".

The thing is that i have to Write code that would take any string containing only lower case letters and spaces and encode it using the crypt dictionary. I have successfully failed trying to write the code so i ended up just using a single print statement 
//print(crypt["h"]!,crypt["i"]!).

If you have any idea you would like to share, please do so.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for:

```
let message = "hi"
let encryptedMessage = message.map { crypt[String($0)]! }.joined()
```

If you're unfamiliar with it, `map`ping a string iterates through each character, doing something to it, and returning that string. `$0` refers to the first parameter (in this case #1 of 1, but 0-indexed).

Comment: Oh yes i was totally unfamiliar with it, i am going to search some documentations to learn about it. Thank you, your answer was very helpful.

Comment: This sounds like a CS homework assignment...

Comment: I am learning Swift, so when i can't make it with the books or videos, or can't reach my professor. I reach out to this website, isn't it what this website was built for ? And it's not like i have posted my assignment....

Answer (score 0):

As Dopapp suggests, map is the most elegant solution. If you want to see the steps broken out a bit, you can do it the long way.

```
var message = "hi"
var crytpedMessage = ""
for char in message {
    let newChar = crypt[String(char)]
    cryptedMessage.append(newChar)
}
```

Comment: I understand a little now, but do you think it is possible to do it as a function ?

Comment: Very possible. You could easily pass in the message as an argument, along with the crypt dictionary to keep it modular, and return cryptedMessage.